# Are all banach space the continuous dual of some other normed space?

Tags: functional-analysis

It's known that if $E^*$ is reflexive so are $E$ and $E^{**}$. My question is if $E$ is banach does exist $F$ (possibly equal to $E$) such that $F^*=E$? And if it does exist can $F$ be not reflexive?
Thank

Comment: Maybe finally read definitions and try $F=E^*$?

Comment: sorry, i made a really stupid typo, i meant "if $E$ is banach does exist..."

Comment: @Vladimir on behalf of the OP being condescending won't really help (I'm referring to the *maybe finally*)

Answer (score 1):

- If $E$ is reflexive, then is a dual space, namely $E=(E^*)^*$
- Converse is false: $\ell^\infty$ is not reflexive, but is a dual space: $\ell^\infty= (\ell^1)^*$